# Poor monitor contrast for certain colors

Tags: display, colors, contrast

I recently bought a monitor (LG W1930S). Everything went out smooth until I discovered certain colors are.. invisible. For instance on this monitor `#EEEEEE` and `#FFFFFF` look the same to me. On the old monitor there is a clear distinction between them. I am using the same (really old) graphic card: nvidia mx 440.

Is this the monitor's fault (do low-end monitors usually fail in this way?) or the graphic card is too old? Thank you in advance.

EDIT:
The thing is I have seen the exact same model at someone else and it showed `#EEEEEE` perfectly. Does this mean I have to return my monitor ?

Comment: check your drivers,make sure it is the correct drivers for your computer

Answer (score 0):

personally i would blame the monitor. different monitors (especially between manufacturers) will display the same image differently, whether because of different programming in the controller or because of different components.

i have a dual monitor setup at home (two different brands) and while one looks OK the other usually looks slightly too green. and no matter how much i fiddle with the controls (either through the graphics drivers or on the monitor itself) i can not get them to look the same.